# How can i format date in groovy script

Tags: groovy

Hi I have a date format that i am getting from my Jira Sprint Environment 2019-03-29T06:56:00.000-04:00

I am using groovy Script.

I have tried to use multiple format to make similar format like the above .
But Unable to do it.
Here are the below solution i have tried.

1 --

```
`def sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"))
log.debug("Printing Current time stamp date : "+sdf)
```

solution 1 is printing text only.

2 --

```
def now = new Date()
println now.format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'",TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC'))
```

this one is printing

```
Printing Current time stamp date : Thu Sep 26 08:00:35 EDT 2019"
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: `println now.format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'",TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC'))` works fine foe me and prints `2019-09-26T15:57:40Z`

Comment: i think you just forgot to assign formatted value to a variable: `def nowStr = now.format(...)`

Comment: but i am not able to know why its working for me like this?"Printing Current time stamp date : Thu Sep 26 08:00:35 EDT 2019"  i want to print like this..  
The end date associated with my Sprint is: "2019-03-29T06:56:00.000-04:00"

Comment: okay let me try ur solution

Comment: Heyy @daggett i am able to see the result but can you help to format this type of Result "2019-03-29T06:56:00.000-04:00"

Comment: [2] makes no sense - this works for me in a 2.5 shell. Have you tried with parens around the println param? `println(now.format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'",TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC')))`

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `OffsetDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the goal is to have date in format

```
2019-03-29T06:56:00.000-04:00
```

the following code does the formatting with timezone GMT-4

```
def now=new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX",TimeZone.getTimeZone('GMT-4'))
println now
```

prints

```
2019-09-26T16:33:18.462-04:00
```

note that the variable `now` will contain `String` with formatted date

Check for all available date & time patterns:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) classes built into Java 8 and later.

Comment: thanks. I used your answer but Edited and didn't use TImeZone parameter.    def now=new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");

Answer (score 1):

Given that you’ve got a Java 8 or newer underneath, all you need is

```
OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toString()
```

In my time zone (Europe/Copenhagen) I just got

> 2019-09-27T21:46:53.336204+02:00

If your default time zone is *America/Montreal* or *America/New_York*, you will get the time at offset -04:00 as long as summer time ([Daylight Saving Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time)) is in effect, then -05:00.

And you can easily parse.

```
OffsetDateTime.parse( "2019-09-27T21:46:53.336204+02:00" )
```

See this [code running at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/bMlo1D).

Answer (score 0):

```
def currentDate = new Date()
def date = currentDate.format('yyyy-MM-dd')
def time = currentDate.format('HH:mm:ss.SSS')
def dateTime = date.toString() + 'T' + time.toString() + 'Z'
```